# Extjs store filter doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, store

I wanted to filter my store but it doesn't work:

```
me.store.filter([{
    filterFn: function(storeItem) {
        Ext.iterate(storeItem.data, function(item) {
            if (item === me.mainMenuItem) {
                if (typeof(storeItem.data[item]) === 'number') {
                    //console.log(storeItem); returns what I want
                    return storeItem;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

When I use this filter my store is empty even if few elements fullfill my conditions. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filterFn` expects you to return a boolean value that indicates whether or not the value matches or not. Currently, you're not returning anything from the `filterFn`, you're returning a value on the inner iteration function, which isn't really useful here.

You want to do something like this:

```
me.store.filter([{
    filterFn: function(rec) {
        var data = rec.data,
            key;

        for (key in data) {
            if (key === me.mainMenuItem && typeof data[key] === 'number') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}]);
```